# Show server ioncube loader version with php

Tags: php, ioncube

I am using ioncube to encode my scripts.

But i don't know the loader version that is installed on sever.

Is there any way or any code or any function to Show the **exact version of IONCUBE** loader version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `phpinfo()`.
If you want to check it's loaded or not, you can use `extension_loaded()`.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Comment: I WANT THE **VERSION** !

Comment: [Check this](http://blog.resellerclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/zend_badge_info.jpeg)

Answer (score 11):

It's an old question, but it's always good to know that the easiest way to find out the exact version of the ionCube Loader is to SSH to the server and type

```
php -v
```

This will give you something like :

```
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (...)
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.7.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd.(...)
```

Comment: best answer for me

Answer (score 6):

If the Loader is installed, you can retrieve this programatically by calling ioncube_loader_version() or ioncube_loader_iversion() in the Loader API.

phpinfo() as suggested will show the Loader version too if the Loader is installed at the time of the call.

The User Guide PDF has more details of the Loader API.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following function. phpinfo not work if listed in disable_functions

```
function GetIonCubeLoaderVersion() {
      if (function_exists('ioncube_loader_iversion')) {
         $version = ioncube_loader_iversion();
         $version = sprintf('%d.%d.%d', $version / 10000, ($version / 100) % 100, $version % 100);
         return $version;
      }
      return 'Not Found!';
}
```

Comment: Nice approach :)

Comment: ioncube_loader_iversion() as mentioned above is generally the best approach as rather than a string it returns an integer that can be easily compared by using numerical methods.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution to get ionCube version from phpInfo:

```
function GetIonCubeLoaderVersion()
{
    ob_start();
    phpinfo(INFO_GENERAL);
    $aux = str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', ob_get_clean());
    if($aux !== false)
    {
        $pos = mb_stripos($aux, 'ionCube PHP Loader');
        if($pos !== false)
        {
            $aux = mb_substr($aux, $pos + 18);
            $aux = mb_substr($aux, mb_stripos($aux, ' v') + 2);

            $version = '';
            $c = 0;
            $char = mb_substr($aux, $c++, 1);
            while(mb_strpos('0123456789.', $char) !== false)
            {
                $version .= $char;
                $char = mb_substr($aux, $c++, 1);
            }

            return $version;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: this feature not work when phpinfo exists in disabe_functions

Comment: Obvious, @Hamid