# The encoded file bootstrap.php is corrupt. in Unknown on line 0 in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on CakePHP 0.2.9. It is working on live but when I try to set it up on my local XAMPP server, it was showing this error:

> Site error: the file
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vacationhosting\core\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php requires
>   the ionCube PHP Loader ioncube_loader_win_5.2.dll to be installed by
>   the site administrator.

When I add the ionCube extension in my php.ini, I am getting this error:

> The encoded file
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\vacationhosting\core\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php is
>   corrupt. in Unknown on line 0.

Comment: Make sure the ioncube version used in your xampp server is compatible with the one used to encode the files (should be backwards compatible).

Comment: how can i check it ioncube is compatible with my xampp with php 5.2

Comment: i don't know how to check its compatible with the one use to encode the file

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835662/show-server-ioncube-loader-version-with-php . Consider upgrading your xampp stack. PHP 5.2 is a bit old. You should be using at least 5.3 or 5.4.

Comment: i am getting the same error on php 5.5 also .

Comment: Check that your ioncube versions match.

Comment: thanx Inigo, can you suggest me how can i decode this encoded file..

Comment: What Ioncube version are you using on both your servers? Check your phpinfo() - http://blog.resellerclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/zend_badge_info.jpeg

Comment: my phpinfo showing this.This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.7, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd

Comment: Is that your development box or your live box? Please post both.

Comment: problem is that i did not encode the file someone else develop this site. site is already working and i don't have live server detail..

Comment: The Loader version is rather old, and one possibility is that the encoded file is in a newer format unrecognised by the Loader. Start by getting the latest Loaders (5.0.19) from the ioncube site and go from there.